# Pushing a knockout observable into a knockout observable array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, ko.observablearray

Being that knockout observable arrays only update on changing an element in the array if that element is itself an observable, I am trying to "push" an element into an observable array but make it observable.  I have tried the following statements, but both result in having an undefined value in my observable array:

```
viewModel.myObservableArray.push(ko.observable());
```

and

```
viewModel.myObservableArray.push(new ko.observable());
```

what would be the correct way to this?

Comment: that is not true. An observable array updates when elements in the observable array are added or removed (the elements themselves need not be observables). if you want to push an observable then you need to do viewModel.myOBservableArray.push(ko.observable('some value')) if it is string or viewModel.MyObservableArray.push(ko.observable({id: 1, name: 'something'}))

Answer (score 2):

Make what you are trying to put in the model an object like this

```
function MyObject(initValuye){
var self = this;
    var value = ko.observable(initValuye);
}
```

In your model

```
viewModel.myObservableArray.push(new MyObject(someValue));
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work, but I was trying to do it with out having to make an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also

```
viewModel.myObservableArray.push(ko.observable("Test"));

viewModel.myObservableArray.push(new ko.observable("Test"));
```